# trace appends your file for rake task in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

While running a rake task in rails 3.1.12 and ruby 1.9.3 ie

```
rake output:generate_files["abc"] --trace>>test1.txt
```

rake task is working fine , but the test1.txt is being appended when this rake task is executed again.

So I would like to know whether there is a method so that each time this rake task is executed it overwrites my test1.txt so that i need not clear this file again and again while running the rake task

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the file if present before doing any write in the rake task:

```
require 'FileUtils'
FileUtils.rm(path_to_txt_file)
# do your job
```

Comment: Here if i have to write a trace to test2.txt , i have to change in path_to_txt_file also , so is there any other way in which it can be handled ..